# How to output ONLY new additions between files with Python Difflib?

Tags: python, difflib

I am comparing two text files using Difflib like so:

```
import difflib

new_file = open(file_name, "r")
old_file = open(old_file_name, "r")

file_difference = difflib.ndiff(old_file.readlines(), new_file.readlines())
```

My goal is to ONLY output additions. I do not want to know about changes to existing lines. However, I've run into a problem where all changes/additions are marked with "+ ", and all subtractions are marked with "- ". I've done a lot of searching, and it appears there's no way to differentiate a line that has been changed, and a line that is brand new. I am confused on how to proceed.

Comment: Could you provide what is expected input and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

f1 = open(old_file_name, "r")

contents1 = f1.read()

f2 = open(file_name, "r",)

contents2 = f2.read()

for data in contents2:

    if data not in contents1:

        file = open(output_path, 'a', newline='')

        # writing the data into the file

        with file:

            write = csv.writer(file)

            write.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn how to use the formatting tools, so that you post code correctly formatted. The help for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). In addition, please try to use consistent indenting with Python code. As you have posted it (I just marked it as a code block) your code will fail with because of the inconsistent indentation.

Answer (score 0):

A great friend of mine provided a code snippet that answered my question:

```
# Open the files for comparison
with open(file_name, "r") as new_file:
    with open(old_file_name, "r") as old_file:
        # Find the differences between the two files
        file_difference = difflib.ndiff(old_file.readlines(), new_file.readlines())

new_lines = []
file_difference = tuple(x for x in file_difference)

idx = 0
fdiff_size = len(file_difference)
while idx < fdiff_size:
    line = file_difference[idx]
    if line.startswith("- "):
        if idx + 1 < fdiff_size and file_difference[idx + 1].startswith("? "):
            # this chunk is a change, so ignore this and the next 3 lines
            idx += 4
            continue
    elif line.startswith("+ "):
        new_lines.append(line)

    # always iterate after new item or no change
    idx += 1
```